# Configuration changes in OpenGL Android app in API 15 and beyond

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing an android game with OpenGL. Having dabbled a little bit with stuff before some time ago, I started tackling the problem of handling activity pausing/resuming and loss of OpenGL context knowing this is a tricky problem. Until now, if I hit the power button and then brought it back on, my app would restart and have all sorts of problems like empty textures. Since restoring the state of the app from scratch is just too much work in my case (there's a bunch of threads, complex AI states that I didn't design with this in mind, that sort of thing) I figured I would drop Gingerbread compatibility, start at Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 15), add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in the manifest and just deal with restoring all things OpenGL. But just looking at how things behaved before pulling up my sleeves, I was surprised to see that everything worked flawlessly with no changes: textures, VBOs... Even the music picks up right where it left off. I've tested this for power off events and the home button. Now I've witnessed this on a Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 (2012) both running Android 4.4.2 and I can't help but feel a little suspicious...

So here are a few questions I was hoping some Android guru could answer:

- Is it OK to do this? Is my app hogging up GPU resources in the background and draining the battery or that kind of thing?
- Can I expect this to also work on previous Android versions? (I have nothing below 4.4.2)
- Can I add calls to the config changes (mcc, mnc <- those are for calls, right?) and it's fine? (I have no way of testing this before a while)
- Are there still cases where the GL context will be lost and I will have to recreate my GL stuff?

Thanks and sorry for the not very broad appeal and unfocused nature of the question (expecting downvotes but this stuff is just so hard to investigate)

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen this work is that the resources actually **are** recreated after a sleep/wake, without the developer having to do much to make that happen. Assuming that you are using a `GLSurfaceView` for your OpenGL rendering, and are following roughly this outline:

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

And then, as documented under "Activity Life-cycle" in the [GLSurfaceView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), you hook up the `onPause()` and `onResume()` handlers in your activity to call the matching methods on the `GLSurfaceView`.

What I generally see happen after sleep/wake (including under 4.4.2) is that the `onSurfaceCreated()` method on the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` implementation gets called again. Since this is where you normally create your OpenGL resources, they are in fact recreated when the device wakes up with the application running.

You can try setting a breakpoint in your `onSurfaceCreated()` and see if it stops there after you wake the device from sleep.

Comment: That can't be the whole story because I create lots of stuff on the fly far from onSurfaceCreated(), and I reuse stuff created before onPause(). My fear is that the behavior you are describing applies to some or all previous versions (I'm targeting 4.0.3 and beyond). Or maybe I was mistaken in thinking that my GL objects would be disposed after onPause()? Unfortunately the GLSurfaceView docs aren't particularly verbose on the subject. I'll keep digging a bit, thanks for the input.